# React integration in PTV xServer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a module using React Framework for Map Routing.
I am trying the JavaScript API [PTV xServer](https://www.ptvgroup.com/en/solutions/products/ptv-xserver/) for route calculation for Trucks but I did not find any documentation in React integration. 
Can anyone tried it before, please help?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late response - I just saw your request. How about this:

There's a generic chapter about how to connect JavaScript based clients to the PTV xServers:
[https://xserver2-europe-eu-test.cloud.ptvgroup.com/dashboard/Default.htm#DevelopersGuide/OVER_Developers-Guide.htm%3FTocPath%3DDeveloper's%2520Guide%7C_____0](https://xserver2-europe-eu-test.cloud.ptvgroup.com/dashboard/Default.htm#DevelopersGuide/OVER_Developers-Guide.htm%3FTocPath%3DDeveloper%27s%2520Guide%7C_____0)

Furthermore there are many samples available at
https://xserver2-europe-eu-test.cloud.ptvgroup.com/dashboard/Default.htm#UseCases/Routing/UC_Calculating_a_route.htm

```
var A = {
    "$type": "OffRoadWaypoint",
    "location": {
        "offRoadCoordinate": {
            "x": 6.1256572,
            "y": 49.5983745
        }
    }
};

var B = {
    "$type": "OnRoadWaypoint",
    "location": {
        "coordinate": {
            "x": 6.1256572,
            "y": 49.4816576
        }
    }
};

xroute.calculateRoute({
    "waypoints": [A, B]
}, routingCompleted);

function routingCompleted(route, exception) {
    print(route.distance + 'm in ' + route.travelTime + 's');
}
```